# How to put data from CSV file to Perl hash

Tags: perl, csv, hash

I have Perl and CSV file with something like:

```
"Name","Lastname"
"Homer","Simpsons"
"Ned","Flanders"
```

In this CSV file I have header in the first line and in other lines there are
data.

I want to convert this CSV file to such Perl data:

```perl
[
    {
        Lastname => "Simpsons",
        Name     => "Homer",
    },
    {
        Lastname => "Flanders",
        Name     => "Ned",
    },
]
```

I've written the function that users [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV) and doing what I need.
Here is the sample script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use 5.010;
use utf8;
use open qw(:std :utf8);

use Text::CSV;

sub read_csv {
    my ($filename) = @_;

    my @first_line;
    my $result;

    my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 });
    open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", $filename or die "$filename: $!";
    while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {
        if (not @first_line) {
            @first_line = @{$row};
        } else {
            push @{$result}, { map { $first_line[$_] => $row->[$_] } 0..$#first_line };
        }
    }
    close $fh;

    return $result;
}

my $data = read_csv('sample.csv');
```

This works fine but this function I want to use in several scripts. I'm
greatly suprised that Text::CSV doesn't have this feature.

My question. What should I do to simplify solving such tasks in the future for
me and others?

Should I use some Perl module from CPAN, should I try to add this function to
Text::CSV, or something else?

Comment: I'd contact the author of ``Text::CSV`` and ask if he'd accept a patch. If you create your own module, you'll be sole responsible for keeping it up to date. Judging from the list of authors, it seems that the module is being actively maintained.

Comment: Regardless of if you put it on the CPAN, do you know how to create pacakges and how they work, or are you looking more for the right thing to do, and not how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Huh? Why so complicated? First, we fetch the header outside of the loop:

```
my $headers = $csv->getline($fh) or die "no header";
```

Assign these to be the column names:

```
$csv->column_names(@$headers);
```

Then, each call to `getline_hr` will provide a hashref:

```
while (my $hashref = $csv->getline_hr($fh)) {
  push @$result, $hashref;
}
```

We can also use `getline_hr_all`:

```
$result = $csv->getline_hr_all($fh);
```

---

In other words, it ain't complex, most pieces are already provided by `Text::CSV`, and it can be done in very few lines.

Also, a module like this seems to already exist: [`Text::CSV::Slurp`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV%3a%3aSlurp). (note: reverse dependency search through metacpan is awesome)

Comment: Thank you for the idea to use reverse dependency in metacpan. I've knew about that feature, but I didn't realized to use it in this question. Yes, usage of the existing module is the best possible choice.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a standard feature because different people will want their CSV files parsed into different data structures.

Why not create your own module that wraps this function?

```
package CSVRead;

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use open qw(:std :utf8);

use Text::CSV;
require Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw(read_csv);

sub read_csv {
    my ($filename) = @_;

    my @first_line;
    my $result;

    my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 });
    open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", $filename or die "$filename: $!";
    while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {
        if (not @first_line) {
            @first_line = @{$row};
        } else {
            push @{$result}, { map { $first_line[$_] => $row->[$_] } 0..$#first_line };
        }
    }
    close $fh;

    return $result;
}
```

Then, use it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Data::Dumper;
use CSVRead;

my $data = read_csv('sample.csv');

say Dumper $data;
```